# Existe um modo de chamar uma função C em C#?

Tags: c#, c

Digamos que eu tenha uma biblioteca com uma função em C, que foi compilada usando o gcc, há como chamar essa função no C#, se sim qual seria o desempenho dela comparada a mesma função criada em C#?

Comment: Não da para medir o desempenho porque na pergunta vc não adicionou o código correspondente da função, e tbm estou em dúvida em relação ao que vc quer. Vc deseja medir o desempenho de uma função em C ou vc precisa chamar uma função em C através do C#?

Comment: É uma função genérica qualquer que execute um loop por exemplo de 65.000 vezes e me retorne algum valor, se por acaso o C consegui-se executar a uma taxa mais rápido que o C# iria se mais pratico usar uma função em C do que C#, ficou claro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiro você tem que exportar a função no seu C.

Por exemplo

```
//Exemplo.dll
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) double funcaoExemplo (int valor)
{
   //código
}
```

e no seu C# você deve usar o [DllImport](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984739(v=vs.71).aspx)

```
   [DllImport("Exemplo.dll")]
   private static extern double funcaoExemplo (int valor);

   public double Teste (int value)
   {
      return funcaoExemplo(value);
   }
```

Em relação ao desempenho o C tem vantagem sobre este aspecto, pois C é uma linguagem *compilada*, enquanto o C# é uma linguagem *semi-compilada*, que dependente do framework.

Comment: No caso quando a função C for chamada ela não ira sofrer nenhum influencia da plataforma .NET certo?

Comment: Apenas na chamada, por causa do DllImport, mas não durante a "execução do método"

Comment: A resposta está incompleta. Para exportar um símbolo em uma dll é necessário usar "__declspec(dllexport)". O exemplo da resposta fica assim: **extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) double funcaoExemplo (int valor)**.

Comment: Obrigado @JoséX. irei corrigir!

Comment: Vale lembrar que, se a dll do c++ for compilada em uma arquitetura diferente do que o programa em c#, pode dar erro de runtime.